# Scrapy DOWNLOAD_DELAY isn't working if it is more then 60

Tags: python, scrapy

I need the DOWNLOAD_DELAY to be 450 seconds (7.5 minutes). In **settings.py** file I set the variable accordingly

```py
DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 450
```

However, when I do that, the real delay I get in logs is 60 seconds.

```
2023-06-29 16:55:39.800 | INFO     | scrapy.extensions.logstats:log:54 - Crawled 1 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)

...

2023-06-29 16:56:39.248 | INFO     | scrapy.extensions.logstats:log:54 - Crawled 2 pages (at 1 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
```

I've tried setting **AUTOTHROTTLE_MAX_DELAY** and **AUTOTHROTTLE_START_DELAY** to the desired value of 450, but the result didn't change.

So, my question is: how do I make my spider run its actions once a 7.5 minutes, instead of once 1 minute?

Comment: you need to set CONCURRENT_REQUESTS to 1

Comment: Posted 2 log records is not enough to check this (too many options can affect this).
Can You make another test (half hour at least) and post here(update in question) at least 25 consequitive `scrapy.extensions.logstats:log:54` log records ( that cover at least `3 * expected delay`)?
Run with `LOG_LEVEL='INFO'` setting will produce only these log records (on the most of cases).

Comment: ```CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 1``` somehow solved my problem! Thanks @Alexander